# Vue Single File Components, how to mount multiple?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Having an `index.js` file like this:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'hello': Hello,
        'counter': Counter,
        'goodbye': GoodBye
    }
});
```

And an `index.html` file like this:

```
<div id="app">
    <Counter />
    <Goodbye />
    <Hello />
</div>
```

Only the first item inside `#app` is rendered.

As is, `Counter` shows ok. If I jump `Goodbye` or `Hello` up, they will also render perfectly.

I obviously would like all of them to render. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML Does not support closing tags with />, its bahaves as the tag is not closed.

This means your structure looks like the following to the browser (check you elements with javascript disabled):

```
<div id="app">
    <Counter>
        <Goodbye>
            <Hello>
            </Hello>
        </Goodbye>
    </Counter>
</div>
```

This will of course not work, we need to update index.html to:

```
<div id="app">
    <Counter></Counter>
    <Goodbye></Goodbye>
    <Hello></Hello>
</div>
```

Comment: Will accept in 7 minutes but you just saved me a ton of time... I was looking into completely different directions. Many many thanks!

Comment: @Frankie Here is a link to the style guide of Vue, the only place I can seem to indicate this problem: https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended